# pymongo- upsert not able to perform insertion with $set operation

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, upsert

I am having an empty collection and have thousands of entries to process (entries might have redudancy for which I want to use both updates and inserts).
The python code (using pymongo) I wrote:

```
for mydoc in alldocs:
   key = {'myid': mydoc['myid']}
   data = process_doc(mydoc)    # returns simple dictionary
   db.mydocs.update(key, {"$set": data}, upsert = True)
```

The following code is unable to perform any insert operations. The collection still remains empty. But when I remove $set and use simply data, it works fine. Can't I use $set in upsert? The reason why I want $set was so that pre-existing fields for a BSON doesn't get affected. Can someone please guide. I really can't figure out what to do.

Reproducable code:

```
from pymongo import Connection
DB_CONTENT_BASE_KEY = 'contentbase'

def connect_to_db(dbname, hostname = 'localhost', portno = 27017, **kwargs):
    connection = Connection(hostname, portno)
    dbConnection = connection[dbname]
    return dbConnection

class MetawebCustomCollectionBuilder(object):
    # key ought to be a dictionary to filter results from contentbase.
    def __init__(self, inDbConfig, outDbConfig, key = {}, verbose = False):
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.inDbConfig = inDbConfig
        self.inDb = connect_to_db(**inDbConfig)
        self.outDbConfig = outDbConfig
        self.outDb = connect_to_db(**outDbConfig)
        self.inDbContentBase = self.inDb[self.inDbConfig[DB_CONTENT_BASE_KEY]]
        self.outDbContentBase = self.outDb[self.outDbConfig[DB_CONTENT_BASE_KEY]]
        self.key = key
        self.in_db_collection_constraints()
        self.out_db_collection_constraints()

    def in_db_collection_constraints(self):
        self.inDbContentBase.ensure_index('mid')
        if self.verbose: print("Assured index on mid for inDbContentBase...")

    def out_db_collection_constraints(self):
        self.outDbContentBase.ensure_index('mid')
        if self.verbose: print("Assured index on mid for outDbContentBase...")

    def process_in_record(self, inRecord):
        outRecord = inRecord # [YET TO] continue from here...
        return outRecord

    def transit_collection(self):
        for record in self.inDbContentBase.find(self.key):
            outRecord = self.process_in_record(record)
            key = {'mid':outRecord['mid']}
            data = outRecord
            print key
            self.outDbContentBase.update(key, {"$set": data}, True)
        if self.verbose: print 'Done with transiting collection from in DB to out DB'

    def cleanup_out_collection(self):
        pass

    def in_db_sandbox(self):
        # To have tests and analytics placed in here corresponding to inDb.
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    inDbConfig = {'dbname':'metaweb', 'contentbase': 'content'}
    outDbConfig = {'dbname': 'similarkind', 'contentbase': 'content'}
    mccb = MetawebCustomCollectionBuilder(inDbConfig, outDbConfig, verbose = True)
    mccb.transit_collection()
```

There must be a prexisting database inDb. From this collection I want to create a new modified collection.

Comment: Provide a reproducable code example.

Comment: You mean the code that was able to perform insertions.

Comment: Provide a code sample that we can copy/paste and try ourselves...we have no obligation adjusting your code in order to get to a code sample we can try...that's your task, not ours.

Comment: I have given the reproducable code in my question itself. :)

Comment: Check out transit_collection() method.

Comment: I said a *reasonable* reproducable example. Your claim is that " db.mydocs.update(key, {"$set": data}, upsert = True)" does not work. So provide a two or three lines where you demonstrate this behavior with an example for *key* and *data*.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16458/discussion-between-sushant-gupta-and-esaelpsnoromon)

Comment: no, provide the sample code as requested

Comment: db.mydocs.update({'myid': '438'}, {"$set": {'keyA':'valueA'}}, upsert = True) # this code do not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your claim is *wrong*

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> c = pymongo.Connection()

>>> db = c.mydb
>>> db.mydocs.find().count()
0
>>> db.mydocs.update({'myid': '438'}, {"$set": {'keyA':'valueA'}}, upsert = True)
>>> db.mydocs.find().count()
1
>>> db.mydocs.find_one()
{u'myid': u'438', u'keyA': u'valueA', u'_id': ObjectId('504c2fd1a694cc9624bbd6a2')}
```

Comment: But in my actual code it is not working. Anyways thanks for your time and help, I will try figure it out.

Comment: Then you are doing something different than what you explained. As said: your claim about update() is wrong.

Comment: In addition: enable safe=True

Comment: I got the problem. When using $set, the data must have ObjectId popped out from it. Its working now :)